# Есть ли в linux fedora live-server для написания html css?

Tags: python, html, css, visual-studio-code

Заинтересовал такой вопрос: есть ли в терминале linux fedora программа которая похожа на расширение из vs code live-server если есть то как ее использовать. То есть просто локальная страница в браузере для отображения html. Просто недавно перешел с vs code в vim и хотелось иметь похожее на это расширение.

Comment: а `python -m http.server` не устроит?

Comment: а как сделать чтоб он отображала определенный html документ? (извините если ответ элементарен)

Comment: документация: By default, this will run the contents of the directory on a local web server, on port 8000.

Comment: спасибо помогли.

Answer (score 0):

можно самому поставить nginx или apache и все.
`apt install nginx`
и открой в браузере http://127.0.0.1
файлы настроек в /etc/nginx, там найдешь и путь где по дефолту лежит файл html для тестовой страницы.